# Constructing HTML table as Email Data in controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, wcf, email

I have C# code for sending Email (in Controller), that is working fine, Email gets shoot with no Problem

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(string msg, int formNum)
{
    var sent = false;
    try
    {
        var emailClient = new EmailServiceReference.EmailServiceClient();
        sent = emailClient.SendEmail(fromEmail, toEmail, emailsubject+""+ formNum, msg);
        // from and to values are defined. 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while sending Email " + ex.Message);
    }
    return Json(sent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you can see there are two parameters for SendEmail() method "msg" & "formNum". I am using those parameters to send the email as Subject(formNum) and Body(msg).

Now, I have 8- 10 parameters getting in SendEmail(FirstName, LastName, ID, Age, PhoneNumber, etc) Method and those I want to use in Email Body. The task for me is to create HTML table in Email body with all details and email it to XYZ@xyz.com

I need help to construct data in HTML table with data in Controller and how can I send it as argument (msg) in method call.?

Thank You

Comment: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=create+html+email+body+c%23&oq=create+html+email+body+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.11116j0j4&client=ms-android-asus-tpin&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: One rudimentary way of doing this is by putting some placeholder in a template file, reading the template and then replace corresponding placeholders with actual value. `e.g. ##PHONE_NUMBER##`

Comment: What is `formNum`?

Comment: It is data coming from View

Comment: I can see `msg` is the data in `HTML` format. But still not sure what is `formNum`. Is it the mail subject?

Comment: I edited post for you

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. See if this works.

```
using System.Net.Mail;

//...

public ActionResult SendEmail(string msg, int formNum)
{
    var sent = false;
    try
    {
        var emailClient = new SmtpClient();
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail);
        mailMessage.Subject = emailsubject +" " + formNum;
        mailMessage.Body = msg;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        emailClient.Send(mailMessage);
        sent = true;
        // from and to values are defined. 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while sending Email " + ex.Message);
    }
    return Json(sent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```